# Running script as a farm administrator

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, script, password, farm-admin

I'm trying to run a script that will generate all of the system account passwords. I have run it the past, but now when I try to run it I get an error that says

> `You need to have Farm administrator privileges to this cmdlet`.

My user is a member of the Farm Administrator Group...what am I doing wrong? Is there something I am missing? Do I need to add my username to each Site Collection?

Comment: What u mean system account password, is it SharePoint managed account or something else? Or you trying to create new password for other accounts and store in SharePoint site collection

Comment: I am getting to get all of the SharePoint managed account passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run this script, please make sure couple of things.

- You Should Login With Farm Admin Account (an account which is running the central admin and timer service). You own account which is part of farm admin group is not enough to run this script.
- Or If You Have Another Account which shell rights on the all dbs in the farm.
- Always try to open the PowerShell windows as an admin.

I used this script to retrieve the saved password.https://melcher.it/2015/04/retrieve-managed-account-passwords-for-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I was able to run the script without any issues. Thank you

Comment: thats good news. happy happy

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure the following**

- You're running the SharePoint Management Shell As Administrator.
- The Farm Administrator is a member of `Local Administrator Group`.
- If it's not working, Try to Run the script via the `Farm Account` that used during configuring the SharePoint.

> **Note:** if your script has New-SPWeb, the account should be added as a Site Collection Administrator

Comment: I will check settings tomorrow morning

Comment: Take your time, hope it working!